# SAS proc score procedure

Tags: sas

SAS give the predicted value name MODEL1 directly. Is there any way to self define the name within proc score procedure?

```
proc score data=DATA score=regout out=score_temp type=parms;
var &_varinclude.;
run;
```

Comment: Provide sample data (or available SASHELP datasets) so that we can understand what variable names you are talking about. At least show the variable names in `regout` and `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a statement label to the model statement.

```
proc reg outest=stat data=sashelp.class plots=(none);
   agePredicted:model age = height weight;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc score score=stat predict data=sashelp.class type=parms;
   var height weight;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```